# How to a sub-string from middle of a string

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

I have a string of "YYYY-MM-DD" and want to convert that string to integers and store them separately as year, month, day. I used `substr` and got year but I couldn't get MM and DD.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int dayOfYear(string date)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++)
    {
        if (date[i] == '-')
            date.erase(date.begin()+i);
    }
        //getting substring for year
    string str1 = date.substr(0, 4);

    string str2 = date.substr(5, 6);//getting wrong output

        //converting string to int
    int year = stoi(str1);
    int month = stoi(str2);

    return month;//getting output as 109


}

int main()
{
    string date = "2019-01-09";
    int p = dayOfYear(date);
    cout << p;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of [`string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is supposed to be the count -- the number of characters to include in the returned string.

After the `-` are removed, `date` is `"20190109"`. You ned to start at position `4` and get `2` characters from date. Use

```
string str2 = date.substr(4, 2);
```

Comment: This solution returns the month, but the function is named **day**OfYear(). After removing the `-` characters, the day is `date.substr(6, 2)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `std::string::substr()` correctly. You are giving it two indexes (and wrong indexes at that), but it expects an index and a count instead.

There is no need to `erase()` the `-` characters (besides, your loop is broken anyway because you don't re-adjust `i` after each `erase()`, so you are skipping characters). You can use `std::string::find()` to find the indexes of the `-` characters, and then use those indexes to calculate the values needed for `std::string::substr()`.

```cpp
int yearOfDate(std::string date)
{
    size_t ends = date.find('-');
    //getting substring for year string
    string str = date.substr(0, end);
    //converting string to int
    return std::stoi(str);
}

int monthOfDate(std::string date)
{
    size_t start = date.find('-') + 1;
    size_t end = date.find('-', start);
    //getting substring for month string
    string str = date.substr(start, end - start);
    //converting string to int
    return std::stoi(str);
}

int dayOfDate(std::string date)
{
    size_t start = date.find('-');
    start = date.find('-', start + 1) + 1;
    //getting substring for day string
    string str = date.substr(start);
    //converting string to int
    return std::stoi(str);
}

int main()
{
    string date = "2019-01-09";
    int y = yearOfDate(date);
    int m = monthOfDate(date);
    int d = dayOfDate(date);
    std::cout << y << ' ' << m << ' ' << d;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you are using C++11 or later (by virtue of using `std::stoi()`), consider using [`std::get_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) instead:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    string date = "2019-01-09";
    std::tm t = {};
    std::istringstream(date) >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y-%m-%d");
    int y = tm.tm_year + 1900;
    int m = tm.tm_mon + 1;
    int d = tm.tm_mday;
    std::cout << y << ' ' << m << ' ' << d;
    return 0;
}
```

In C++20, you can use [`std::chrono::from_stream(std::chrono::year_month_day)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/from_stream) instead:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    string date = "2019-01-09";
    std::istringstream iss(date);
    std::chrono::year_month_day ymd;
    std::from_stream(iss, "%Y-%m-%d", ymd);
    unsigned y = ymd.year();
    unsigned m = ymd.month();
    unsigned d = ymd.day();
    std::cout << y << ' ' << m << ' ' << d;
    return 0;
}
```